# React Material UI Dialog Failed prop type value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui

Posting at my wits end. I'm not a developer, this is just a home project.

I was trying to build a reusable Dialog (that just asks 'Are you sure?), and kept getting errors.

Now, I've taken the example from Material UI

[Material UI Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/)

and demo

[Material UI Dialog Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6r757?file=/demo.js:369-573)

And implemented a copy of it myself:

DialogTest.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';


export default function DialogTest() {

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };
  
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Dialog</h2>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Open Dialog</button>
            </div>
            <Dialog
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Boom</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                        Blah
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                        Disagree
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                        Agree
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

import React from 'react';
import DialogTest from './DialogTest';
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <DialogTest/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Apart from changing the text, I cannot see a difference, yet I get the following error when opening the Dialog (and the buttons do not render):

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Dialog)`, but its value is `undefined`.

I had this error when implementing my reusable solution, which is why I stripped it back to the above code.

I checked the React debug tools, and they say the Dialog has a prop of 'open' defined.

So I am at a loss :(

Does anyone have a pointer as to what is going on? My guess is I have a stupid error, but I can't find it.

Comment: Your button import is incorrect. Change it to ```import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";```

Comment: Oh my goodness I am so sorry!!!!! I have been staring at this for hours! Thank you so so much.

Comment: <DialogTest/> the warning is because you are not passing the prop open, to avoid the. warning <DialogTest open/> you can pass like this or you can use useState to hold the value

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS - no, I am passing the open in Dialog, it's declared in the state. The answer of szczocik was the correct issue - I was effectively nesting Dialogs due to an incorrect import. The nested Dialog then had no open prop set.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed my error - my import at the top is incorrect.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
```

should be

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button;
```

Thank you to the kind person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
open={open || fasle}
```

I do this like and fixed!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).